# Cakephp 3.0 - Load Model inside Component

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

How to load a Model inside a Component in Cakephp 3.0?
Before(in Cakephp 2) you could use

```
$Model = ClassRegistry::init($modelName);
$Model->create(false);
$saved = $Model->save($data);
```

Whats the equivalent of that in 3.0?

Comment: I'd suggest to consult the docs first for such basic stuff http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As pointed out before, you can use the TableRegistry to access a model:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
$this->Articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
```

[See here for documentation.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html#quick-example)

Answer (score 7):

As someone said in the comments, you should at least read the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html) to understand what the differences with 3.0 are. To address your specific question, you now can use the `TableRegistry`:

```
$table = TableRegistry::get($tableName);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Accessing a Component’s Controller**

From within a Component you can access the current controller through the registry:

```
$controller = $this->_registry->getController();
```

for more please read this link : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I've done is to build a loadModel class in the component. This keeps my code consistent.

```
namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class MyComponent extends Component {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->loadModel('Users');
    }

    private function loadModel($model) {
        $this->$model = TableRegistry::get($model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use loadModel which adds the instance to the controller as a property then that's how you do it.

```
class ArticleComponent extends Component
{
    public function initialize(array $config) 
    {
        $this->controler = $this->_registry->getController();
    }

    public function myFunction($id)
    {
        $this->controller->loadModel('Articles');
        $article = $this->controller->Articles->get($id);

        debug($article);
    }
}
```

This way is like telling controller to open a model for you:

> $article = $component->controller->UserModel;

But when you can call a model straight away using `TableRegistry` what's the point of calling controller to call a model for you.

> $article = $component->UserModel;

Long story short `loadModel()` is a wrapper for `TableRegistry`

Comment: Why not just use the ModelAwareTrait inside a class.  then you can use $this->loadModel() like in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is same approch other answers. but, I try to save record inside component.

In this case, code is like following...

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
---
$model = TableRegistry::get('MyModeles');
$entity = $model->newEntity();
$entity->set('filed1', 'newValue');
....
$model->save($entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamic access to table with the next snippet:

```php
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class TestComponent extends Component {
    private $controller;
    private $table;
    public function startup(Event $event) {
        $this->controller = $event->getSubject();
        $this->table = TableRegistry::get($this->controller->name);
    }
}
```